# Read SMS from Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, sms, message

I try read input messages in my phone.
I used

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageStore store = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageManager.RequestStoreAsync();
var msgList = store.GetMessageReader();
IReadOnlyList<Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage> a = await msgList.ReadBatchAsync();
```

and how i want get my messages property

```
            foreach (var item in a)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.Body);
            }
```

but i have Error:

> Access is denied.

Comment: From [Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.chat.aspx): *"This API is not available to all Windows/Windows Phone apps. Unless your developer account is specially provisioned by Microsoft, calls to these APIs will fail at runtime."*

Comment: @IInspectable but there's another way to get a message from your phone?

Comment: If your developer account isn't provisioned to use this API, then clearly Microsoft doesn't want you to read those messages. Why do you assume that Microsoft would offer an alternative to side-step their protection scheme?

Comment: @IInspectable as well as the access to the use of the API?

Comment: If you dont have a provisioned account which allows you to use the api the only work around is to check with the phone carrier and see if there is a rest service which lets you get there messages